# How can I make jquery plugin bigtext draggable and editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, contenteditable

searching through this forum has been invaluable but I now have a problem I can't find any answers for, I am new to jQuery and javascript, or any coding, so please bear with me, I'll try to explain it as clearly as I can.

I am trying to create a textbox using the jquery plugin bigtext, I need the textbox to be draggable and able to be edited by the user with the text updating on every keyup. The textbox will have a set width.

Using some past answers on this forum I have been able to create a textbox that is draggable however when the user enters text the bigtext plugin no longer works and does not adjust the text height to fit the width

HTML

```
<div id="d" >
<div id="e" contenteditable="true">edit me</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#d").draggable()
.click(function () {
$(this).draggable({
    disabled: false
});
}).dblclick(function () {
$(this).draggable({
    disabled: true
});
});
$("#d").bigtext();
```

CSS

```
#d {

width:300px;
border: 1px dashed;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grhm/r6GSS/3/

I am also able to create a textbox where the user enters there text and it outputs to a different box, the bigtext plugin works in the output textbox but when I try to make the box draggable it stops working

HTML

```
Enter text Here <input id="input" value="Edit This">
<div id="Mainbox" style="width:300px;border:1px dashed">
<div id="preview">Edit This</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function () {

var update = function () {
    $(" #preview").text($("#input")[0].value);
    $("#Mainbox").bigtext().draggable();
    }
    $("#input").on("keyup", update)
    update();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TgafU/4/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Everything seems to be working in your first jsfiddle in Chrome (I can edit the text, and drag it around)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. The problem is the bigtext plugin is supposed to force the text to stay at the same width meaning the height should adjust depending on the length of the text entered, instead the edited text is remaining at its original size

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that the text needs to stay on one line, I tried adding   'white-space:nowrap;' to the css but the text just extended past the width of the box instead of adjusting